# How to get rows ordered by desc from specific ids

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

My goal : Getting Purchase requests ordered by most confirmed shipment locations.

Purchase requests are linked to a shipment location (warehouse).

I have a table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shipment_locations` (
  `id` int(6) primary key,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `shipment_locations` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
  ('1', 'france'),
  ('2', 'usa'),
  ('3', 'spain'),
  ('4', 'germany');
  
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `purchase_requests` (
  `id` int(6) primary key,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `total_cost_confirmed` int(6) NULL,
  `shipment_location_id` int(6) NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY (`shipment_location_id`) REFERENCES `shipment_locations` (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `purchase_requests` (`id`, `name`, `total_cost_confirmed`, `shipment_location_id`) VALUES
  ('1', 'pr1', '109', 1),
  ('2', 'pr2', '1500', 3),
  ('3', 'pr3', '3000', 2),
  ('4', 'pr4', '10000', 2),
  ('5', 'pr5', '5', 3),
  ('6', 'pr6', '3000', 2),
  ('7', 'pr7', '3000', 2),
  ('8', 'pr8', '1', 3),
  ('9', 'pr9', '10000000', 3);
```

For ordering by shipment location that have the most confirmed cost, it's pretty simple :

```
SELECT shipment_location_id, SUM(total_cost_confirmed) totalConfirmed
FROM purchase_requests
GROUP BY shipment_location_id
ORDER BY totalConfirmed DESC
```

It works perfectly here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/732f32/2/0

But, then I tried to filter by purchase request id (adding `GROUP BY id` and `WHERE id IN(...)`) it gives me the wrong order (because it's taking ids present in the result).
=> ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/732f32/2/1))

How I can keep the correct order from the first query while filtering by Purchase request id ?

Adding sqlfiddle : [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/732f32/2)

Thanks by advance for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First aggregate to get the sum of `totalConfirmed` and then join to the table:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.shipment_location_id, t.totalConfirmed
FROM purchase_requests p 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT shipment_location_id, SUM(total_cost_confirmed) totalConfirmed 
  FROM purchase_requests
  GROUP BY shipment_location_id
) t ON t.shipment_location_id = p.shipment_location_id
WHERE p.id IN ('1', '3', '4', '8')
ORDER BY t.totalConfirmed DESC
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8de9f01f798a049bc92c5fccf4187b0a).
Results:

```
> id | name | shipment_location_id | totalConfirmed
> -: | :--- | -------------------: | -------------:
>  4 | pr4  |                    2 |          19000
>  3 | pr3  |                    2 |          19000
>  8 | pr8  |                    1 |            110
>  1 | pr1  |                    1 |            110
```

Comment: impossible to keep the total confirmed per shipment locations and retrieving the correct purchase request id and name ?

Comment: Which id and name do you consider as *correct* for each of the `shipment_location_id`s 1, 2 and 3?

Comment: Here is the result I need : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/600224/2

Comment: (see the last comments in the fiddle)